# How i can add two surfaces to famo.us Scrollview?

Tags: famo.us

I want to create Scrollview with two surfaces, one for the background and the other one for text vertically and horizontal aligned, but i just dont figure it out. Tried with ContainerSurface but seems no to be the best perfomance option. any thoughts?

Comment: Is this still the same question you were asking in irc? If so, do you mean two surfaces in each item of the scrollview or are you looking to put two items total in the scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways. Here are a few examples:

1. Add a single surface and as a content add a div for the text:

   ```
   var surface = new Surface({
       size: [undefined, 50],
       classes: ['mysurface'],
       content: '<div>my text</div>'
   });
   surfaces.push(surface); // add to surfaces array
   ```

in the css, add your styling:

```
    .mysurface {
        background: 'red'
    }

    .mysurface div {
        text-alignment: center;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
```

2. Create multiple surfaces and put them in a RenderNode:

   ```
   var renderNode = new RenderNode(new Modifier({
       size: [undefined, 50]
   }));

   // Add background surface to rendernode
   var backSurface = new Surface({
       classes: ['mysurface']
   });
   renderNode.add(backSurface);

   // Add text surface and translate it in z-space 1 unit so it lies in front of backSurface
   var textSurface = new Surface({
       content: 'this is the text'
   });
   renderNode.add(new Modifier({
       transform: Transform.translate(0, 0, 1) 
   })).add(textSurface);

   // Add to scrollview
   surfaces.push(renderNode);
   ```
3. Create an actual view and add that to the scrollview (see famo.us university)
4. Use a layout view/solution like famous-flex:

   ```
   var item = new LayoutController({
       layout: function(context, options) {
          var dock = new LayoutDockHelper(context, options);
          dock.fill('back'); // size back to fill whole content
          dock.margins(5); // indent 5 pixel margins all around
          dock.fill('text'); // fill text to remaining inner space
       },
       dataSource: {
          back: new Surface({...}),
          text: new Surface({...}),
       }    
   });
   surfaces.push(item);
   ```

https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-flex

Answer (score -1):

You can add it with Sequential Layout like this:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
var Engine           = require("famous/core/Engine");
var Surface          = require("famous/core/Surface");
var SequentialLayout = require("famous/views/SequentialLayout");

var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

var sequentialLayout = new SequentialLayout({
    direction: 1
});
var surfaces = [];

sequentialLayout.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    surfaces.push(new Surface({
         content: "Surface: " + (i + 1),
         size: [undefined, window.innerHeight/10],
         properties: {
             backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 10) + ", 100%, 50%)",
             lineHeight: window.innerHeight/10 + "px",
             textAlign: "center"
         }
    }));
}

mainContext.add(sequentialLayout);
```

});